How to add input and Check Box to Jquery data table
Clicking on My DataTable row displays a child table.
Here I have added two additional columns.
One input type is number, the other is checkbox.
I want to insert the checked items into the dataset
at once on add button click. My requirement is - when I
input the number in the text box then the checkbox
will be auto checked. But I can't do that.
Second Requirement – ​​There will be another checkbox next to
OrderNumber where when clicked the checkboxes of
the child table checkbox will be checked.


 function format(d) {
     debugger
     var str = '';
     $.each(d.tbl_orderses, function (index, data) {
         str += '<tr>' +
             '<td>' + data.productID + '</td><td>' + data.oredrQty + '</td><td><input type="number" value="" class="txt_qty" /></td><td><input type="checkbox" name="Selectone" class="chk_isChecked" id="' + data.productID + '" /></td>' +
             '</tr>'
     });

     return '<table  style="padding-left:50px;">' +
         '<tr>' +
         '<td>ProductID</td><td>oredrQty</td><td>Return Qty</td><td>Check</td>' +
         '</tr>' +
         str +
         '</table>';
 }
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.ajax({
         url: "/Home/Getrecord",
         type: "Get",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
             console.log("succsss" + data);
             var table = $("#example").DataTable({
                 "data": data,
                 "columns": [
                     {
                         "className": 'details-control',
                         "orderable": false,
                         "data": null,
                         "defaultContent": ''
                     },
                 
                     { "data": "orderNumber" },
                     { "data": "totalvalue" },
                 ],
                 "order": [[0, 'desc']]
             });
             $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                 debugger
                 var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                 var row = table.row(tr);
                 if (row.child.isShown()) {
                     row.child.hide();
                     tr.removeClass('shown');
                 }
                 else {
                     row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                     tr.addClass('shown');
                 }
             });
         },
         error: function (ex) {
             console.log(ex);
         }

     });
     bindEvents()
 });
 function bindEvents() {
     $(".txt_qty").off("input").on("input", function () {
         debugger
         var qty = $(this).val();
         if (qty && parseInt(qty) > 0) {
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".chk_isChecked").prop("checked", true);

         } else {
             $(this).closest("tr").find(".chk_isChecked").prop("checked", false);
         }
     });
 }

 function addata() {
     let valudata = []
     let txtqty = []
     $('input[name="Selectone"]:checked').each(function (i, data) { valudata.push(this.id) });
     $(".txt_qty").each(function (i, tm) {
         var txtvalue = $(tm).val();
         if (txtvalue.length > 0 && txtvalue != "0") {
             txtqty.push(txtvalue)
         }
     });
     var objdate =
     {
         'IDS': valudata,
         'qty': txtqty
     };
     $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: '/Home/adddata',
         data: objdate,
         success: function () {
             alert("Success")
         },
         Error: function () {
             alert("Error")
         }
     })
 }



   public JsonResult Getrecord()
 {
     var List = from a in _context.tbl_Orders
                group a by new { a.orderNumber } into g
                select new ordervm
                {
                    orderNumber = g.Key.orderNumber,
                    Totalvalue = g.Sum(x => x.value),
                    tbl_orderses = g.Select(t => new tbl_order
                    {
                        productID = t.productID,
                        oredrQty = t.oredrQty,
                        orderId = t.orderId,
                    }).ToList()
                };
     return Json(List);
 }

enter image description here

Hi Jewel, could you share a minimal sample project( or provide enough code ) to us ? Then we can learn the issue easily. Judging from the code you've provided so far, when you bind events to these dynamically created elements, those elements may not exist in the DOM yet. This should be the cause of the problem, I need enough code to debug.
